# How can I include both quotes and double quotes in a text string in python?

Tags: python, minecraft, quotes, double-quotes

I am trying to automate a Minecraft command that contains both quotes " and '.
When I connect the string variables they make a mess with the quotes that start and finish the string. Is there a way to avoid that?

```
Name = input("User name: ")
Age = input("User age: ")
Sex = input("User gender: ")
Job = input("User job: ")
Final = '/give @s flower_banner_pattern{display:{Lore:['{"text":"Name: " + Name + ","color":"white"}','{"text":"Age: " + Age + ','color":"white"}','{"text":"Sex: " + Sex + ","color":"white"}','{"text":"Job: " + Job + ','color":"white"}']}}'
```

Comment: You could try ```triple quotes``` to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

to indicate quotes and double quotes in python you have to indicate them in the following way:

```
\'-> Single quote for python string

\" -> Two quotes for python String
```

This that I just indicated is only to place those characters in the string, they have nothing to do with the quotes at the beginning and end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Using `'` and `"` simultaneously sometimes would be erroneous. If you intend to use both single and double quotations simultaneously and also multiple quotations, I suggest you use `\` to separate the main and the major quotations. The following example would give you insight into the instruction:

```
myString = 'there is a few quotations such as this \' and this \'. There is no need to use slash with ".'
print(myString)
```

##### Output

```
there is a few quotations such as this ' and this '. There is no need to use slash with ".
```

Comment: I just tried and it worked perfectly! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how Minecraft commands work, but if you start the Final variable with a single quote `'`, then in the middle of the string if you want yto use a single quote, you should do `\'`.

This means that the following should work:

```
Name = input("User name: ")
Age = input("User age: ")
Sex = input("User gender: ")
Job = input("User job: ")
Final = '/give @s flower_banner_pattern{display:{Lore:[\'{"text":"Name: " + Name + ","color":"white"}\',\'{"text":"Age: " + Age + \',\'color":"white"}\',\'{"text":"Sex: " + Sex + ","color":"white"}\',\'{"text":"Job: " + Job + \',\'color":"white"}\']}}'
```